# SQL Server connection string causing error?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

In a Winforms application, I have a connection string that causes an error

```
data source=(local);initial catalog=RegisterDB;persist security info=False
```

Error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Thanks for the help Arif Ansari but it still gives the same error.

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express with SQL Server. I created the database from within Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express

## Can anyone help?

Hi marc_s

Sorry it didnt work. I created the Database RegisterDB manually with  Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Express in server "(localdb)\v11.0"

Can anyone help ???????

Comment: Okay, so there is a very clear description of what caused the error: "The server was not found or was not accessible." and how you might be able to solve it: "Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections." - So what is your question exactly?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try it

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Database=RegisterDB;Integrated Security= true");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this query as your connection string format

```
Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

or this

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

basically check the instance of the server that you are running.

Check if the instance service is running or not.
Type **services.msc** in the start menu to open the Services List.
Check for the name **SQL SERVER (your instance name)**.
If the instance status is **Started**, issue is in your connection string or user permissions.
Else if the status is empty or stopped, start the instance and then try connecting.

you may also refer this [site](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) for connection string format.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server that comes with Visual Studio 2013 is the **2012 Express** version - and that by default install the "LocalDB" support.

So I would try this connection string instead:

```
"data source=(localdb)\v11.0;initial catalog=RegisterDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
```

Does that work? If not: are you auto-creating the database, or if not, did you manually create that database `RegisterDB` that you're referencing in the connection string?